# Скриншоты PhoneGap-приложения для AppStore без XCode и реальных устройств - как?

Tags: xcode, phonegap, appstore, экран, screenshots

Для публикации приложения в AppStore через itunesconnect.apple.com необходимо загрузить скриншоты приложения под разные разрешения.

Как можно обойтись без XCode, ибо у меня Windows и без реальных Apple-устройств.

Comment: сделайте скрины с симулятора

Comment: это что за симулятор? подскажите куда копать где найти?

Comment: а как вы вообще запускали приложение?

Comment: Установил на свой iPhone через сканирование QR-кода из build.phonegap.com и тестил.

Comment: ну так и делайте скрины с него

Comment: ну так если не читали правила Apple, надо с разных экранов разных устройств загрузить скрины для публикации своего приложения. Потому посоветуете искать остальные устройства? ))

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот вам что приходит в голову:

1) нафотошопить скринов. Я так понимаю, что ваше приложение можно просто открыть в браузере в любом размере, и потом прицепить статус бар к скришоту

2) найти все девайсы, и сделать скрины самому.

3) загрузить на testFlight (или через build.phonegap.com) и отправить приглашения друзьям, у которых есть девайсы и попросить их сделать скрины и прислать.

4) создать аккаунт на AWS device farm, загрузить туда свое приложение с парой тестов, которые будут открывать разные экраны, и потом получить видео/скрины с результатами тестов и их использовать.

Comment: 5) Эмулятор Smartface вроде как можно еще заюзать, но пока не знаю как его получить без приглашения )